# Send ssh through tor

Tags: ssh, routing, ssh-tunneling, tor

I want to use **Tor** like this:

> ssh -N -D 8070 user@111.222.333.44 -p 22  --> Tor  --> internet

I understand Tor can be routed `--thru port--> 8070`.  Also or in conjunction tor can be routed through vpn and ssh.

> vpn creates tunnel gateway -> ssh connects to server through the vpn tunnel gateway -> tor uses port 8070 so all tor traffic is going thru vpn + ssh

But can ssh tunnel be sent through Tor like a VPN?
So ssh request can use Tor instead of VPN to get to the internet to create ssh tunnel with server .

> ssh request -> tor -> ssh server -> server accepts login -> tunnel complete -> exit point to clear internet

Is this basically torifying [like this](https://www.ondarknet.com/tech/how-to-run-an-ssh-connection-through-tor/)?
Is there a way to send ssh through Tor without having root access to ssh server as described in link?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is really unclear. Your question is "Can I use SSH through Tor", and you're linking an article titled "How to run an SSH connection through Tor"?

Comment: 1) `ssh uses tor instead of vpn` SSH goes out of your system the same way any other traffic does, through a gateway. If your traffic is VPN:d, it goes through a different gateway and SSH will go through that VPN. If you start TOR with a VPN connection, TOR connects through that VPN. 2) `Is there a way to send ssh through tor without having root access to ssh server` You don't SSH _out_ to the internet, you SSH _in_ to a remote system _over_ the internet. There _must_ be an SSH server to connect _to_. The article says nothing about root access.

Comment: the ssh server to reach is not in local network so to connect to it the ssh connection request must be routed to the internet.  the article (torifying ssh) says `The first thing you must do is install Tor. You'll need to do this on both the client and the server,` but i do not have root access or permissions to install anything - i can only use the ssh server to tunnel connections onward.

Comment: The first thing you must do is install but you don't have the privileges to install... it's still unclear what you want to do. Tunnel TOR over SSH, or SSH over TOR? Do you want to set up an SSH server that's only reachable through onion? I'm not sure if the concepts are entirely clear to you. Don't take it the wrong way - maybe it's because you're only starting with networking, or maybe because English isn't your mother tongue; nothing wrong with either, just makes it a bit hard to follow :-) Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) would help you clarify the question.

Comment: `ssh` can be tunneled through *everything* via its `-o ProxyCommand` option. Unfortunately I'm not able to give you an example right now, but you may figure out yourself until I get back to it.

Comment: @Peregrino69 you don't need any :internet" to run a ssh client or server. Go read about `ProxyCommand` in `man ssh_config` and the `-i` option in `man sshd`. Your comments are not productive.

Comment: @UncleBilly 1) Please _do_ provide an example of tunneling SSH through SNTP using ProxyCommand. 2) Please _do_ provide an example of using a keyfile to establish a connection between your SSH client and an SSH server not located in the same system or network segment, _without_ crossing the internet. I'm asking questions because I want to understand OP:s intent so I can advise him. Are you absolutely convinced that your two comments above are more productive towards that goal?

Comment: @Peregrino69 **1.** Do you suggest that I won't be able to channel ssh through a firewall which only allows udp on port 123? You can make that challenge in a separate question (though this site is not very good for such coding challenges, and the local culture is geared towards copy-pasting google results and getting rep points, so I'm not sure that it would be well received here ;-)).

Comment: @UncleBilly Heck no, I'm sure you're _at least_ as proficient an SSH user as myself :-)